# Spring and Hibernate: form for object containing objects

Tags: java, forms, spring, hibernate

There are an entity called "Person" and an entity called "Course" with relation many to many. The join entity is called "PersonCourse".

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person_course")
public class PersonCourse implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="course_ID")
    private Course course;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_ID")
    private Person person;

    // Getter and setters here
}
```

I've the following form with which I'm supposed to persist information to "PersonCourse":

```
<form:form method="post" action="addpersoncourse.html" commandName="personcourse">

    <form:label path="person"><spring:message code="label.person"/></form:label>

    <form:select path="person">
        <c:forEach items="${personList}" var="person">
            <form:option value="${person.id}">${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}</form:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>  

    <form:label path="course"><spring:message code="label.course"/></form:label>

        <form:select path="course">
            <c:forEach items="${courseList}" var="course">
                <form:option value="${course.id}">${course.course}</form:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>  


        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addpersoncourse"/>"/>
</form:form>
```

In the controller I'm trying to read the information with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addpersoncourse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addpersoncourse(@ModelAttribute("personcourse")
PersonCourse personCourse, BindingResult result) {  

    // HERE personcourse.person and personcourse.course ARE NULL

// Other operation I'm supposed to do
}
```

But for some reason personcourse.person and personcourse.course are null. What may be wrong?

Comment: did you already make sure the data already saved in your database? and with that method of your, you can get personcourse?

Comment: yes, I've data in all three the tables and I can retrieve that data without problems. The only problem is here when I try to save personcourse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change to:

```
<form:select path="person.id">
<form:select path="course.id">
```

or try to use `Formatters`.